# <br> not breaking lines in forms with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to get a form layout like below

https://jsfiddle.net/May_Y/6w9nd73c/20/

```html
<form id="cat_select" class="form-inline">
  <input class="c" name="c" id="c" type="text" style="width:10%"><br><br> Select any below:<br><br>
  <input class="l0" name="l0" id="l0" type="text" style="width:30%">
  <input class="l1" name="l1" id="l1" type="text" style="width:30%">
  <input class="l2" name="l2" id="l2" type="text" style="width:30%">
  <input class="l3" name="l3" id="l3" type="text" style="width:50%">
  <input class="l4" name="l4" id="l4" type="text" style="width:50%">
  <input class="l5" name="l5" id="l5" type="text" style="width:100%">
  <input class="l6" name="l6" id="l6" type="text" style="width:100%">
  <br>
  <input `id="query" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="query" placeholder="optional input" aria-label="query" name='query' value="" style="width:50%">
  <select id="mySelect">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Sort by</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select><br><br>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" id="cat_submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

but if I add bootstrap, `<br>` does not work any more.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.staticfile.org/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<form id="cat_select" class="form-inline">
  <input class="c" name="c" id="c" type="text" style="width:10%"><br><br> Select any below:<br><br>
  <input class="l0" name="l0" id="l0" type="text" style="width:30%">
  <input class="l1" name="l1" id="l1" type="text" style="width:30%">
  <input class="l2" name="l2" id="l2" type="text" style="width:30%">
  <input class="l3" name="l3" id="l3" type="text" style="width:50%">
  <input class="l4" name="l4" id="l4" type="text" style="width:50%">
  <input class="l5" name="l5" id="l5" type="text" style="width:100%">
  <input class="l6" name="l6" id="l6" type="text" style="width:100%">
  <br>
  <input `id="query" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="query" placeholder="optional input" aria-label="query" name='query' value="" style="width:50%">
  <select id="mySelect">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Sort by</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select><br><br>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" id="cat_submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I tried with `<br style="clear: both;">` but it is not working as well.
How can I get the desired format with bootstrap.

I would like to have only `id="query"` and `id="mySelect"` in a different background color. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure why but if you add another `<br/>`, a break line appears in the view

Comment: @JamesS I added the second `<br>` just to see if the second one can start a new line but it does not.

Comment: `.form-inline` uses `display: flex`, meaning all child elements will become flex items, _including `br` tags_. You should not be using `br` tags anyway. They are for adding line breaks in text; not for layout. Use Bootstrap's grid system to manage the layout.

Answer (score 1):

just remove class="form-inline" it will work  see the image[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. `<br>` should work with bootstrap, may be something else is breaking your 
    tag, Can't say anything on this without checking your actual code.
2. To set different background color you need to  create some class in css and set that class to specific elements where you need that backgrund color. (in you case `id="query"` and `id="mySelect"` )

**Style/CSS**
`.classname { background: red; }`

**Add class to elements you need**

```
`<input `id="query" class="form-control mr-sm-2 classname" type="query" placeholder="optional input" aria-label="query" name = 'query'style="width:50%">
<select id="mySelect" class="classname">
   <option value="" disabled selected>Sort by</option>
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
</select>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is absolutely OK. I don't know why do you have any problem, but I suggest you to use downloaded version of Bootstrap (no CDN). This is image what I get on the screen with your code:

[image: Form image]

On the other hand, it's possible to change background color only for query and mySelect ID classes. Here is the image:

[image: Background color]

You only need to add additional classes. In my case there are test and test_2 classes. Check image:

[image: Classes]

Answer (score 0):

`br` are here direct children of a `flex` box and are treated like any flex child *(standing in the flex flow direction)* .

You may use :

- another element and set its width to 100% `<p class="w-100"><!-- will also break a line if boostrap is not loaded --></p>` instead `<br><br>`

*it requires to modify the HTML*

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.staticfile.org/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<form id="cat_select" class="form-inline ">
  <input class="c" name="c" id="c" type="text" style="width:10%"><br><br> Select any below:<br><br>
  <input class="l0" name="l0" id="l0" type="text" style="width:30%">
  <input class="l1" name="l1" id="l1" type="text" style="width:30%">
  <input class="l2" name="l2" id="l2" type="text" style="width:30%">
  <input class="l3" name="l3" id="l3" type="text" style="width:50%">
  <input class="l4" name="l4" id="l4" type="text" style="width:50%">
  <input class="l5" name="l5" id="l5" type="text" style="width:100%">
  <input class="l6" name="l6" id="l6" type="text" style="width:100%">
  <br>
  <input `id="query" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="query" placeholder="optional input" aria-label="query" name='query' value="" style="width:50%">
  <select id="mySelect">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Sort by</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
  <p class="w-100"><!-- will also break a line if boostrap is not loaded --></p>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" id="cat_submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

- or use a pseudo and order

*it requires to add extra css*

```css
#cat_select:after {
content:'';
width:100%;
height:1em;
order:1;
}
#cat_submit {
order:2
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.staticfile.org/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<form id="cat_select" class="form-inline ">
  <input class="c" name="c" id="c" type="text" style="width:10%"><br><br> Select any below:<br><br>
  <input class="l0" name="l0" id="l0" type="text" style="width:30%">
  <input class="l1" name="l1" id="l1" type="text" style="width:30%">
  <input class="l2" name="l2" id="l2" type="text" style="width:30%">
  <input class="l3" name="l3" id="l3" type="text" style="width:50%">
  <input class="l4" name="l4" id="l4" type="text" style="width:50%">
  <input class="l5" name="l5" id="l5" type="text" style="width:100%">
  <input class="l6" name="l6" id="l6" type="text" style="width:100%">
  <br>
  <input `id="query" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="query" placeholder="optional input" aria-label="query" name='query' value="" style="width:50%">
  <select id="mySelect">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Sort by</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select><br><br>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" id="cat_submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```